# cancan Abilty, Devise and Rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, cancan

People, I'm new at RoR enviroment, and I'm trying to do something apparently simple, but its getting complicated.

I do not have roles in my application, and I just want to add some features to logged in users, but starting with the RSpec tests, I cannot find the way to test if the user is signed in...

I'm using CanCan with Devise.

I tried this code below, but it didn't work, says that there is no method called sign_in, I've already tried current_user, and user_signed_in?

```
before(:each) do
  @user = User.new
  sign_in @user
end
```

What am I missing?

gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.0.7'

# authentication
gem 'devise', '~> 1.3.4'

#authorization
gem "cancan"

# mongodb database
gem 'mongoid', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.3'

gem "high_voltage"
gem 'translate_routes'

gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 1.1.rc1"

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0"
  gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 0.3.2"
  gem "webrat", ">= 0.7.2"
  gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'autotest-rails-pure'
  gem 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
  gem 'shoulda'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a spec/support/devise.rb file? It needs to include

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: Still, Failure/Error: sign_in @user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xb66e9bbc>

Comment: Did you run rails generate rspec:install in the root of your application?

Comment: yes, but i did it again and now  its happening another error, its saying that: spec_helper.rb:21: undefined method `fixture_path=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0xb74f5fd0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile also?

Comment: source 'http://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '~> 3.0.7'

    # authentication
gem 'devise', '~> 1.3.4'

#authorization
gem "cancan"

# mongodb database
gem 'mongoid', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.3'

gem "high_voltage"
gem 'translate_routes'

gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 1.1.rc1"

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0"
  gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 0.3.2"
  gem "webrat", ">= 0.7.2"
  gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'autotest-rails-pure'
  gem 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
  gem 'shoulda'
end

Comment: Try with the latest rspec version - use 'gem rspec' instead of "gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'"